# Class of structures isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z},<)$ in infinitary logic $L_{\omega_1 \omega}$

Tags: logic, order-theory, model-theory

We want to define the class of all structures isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z},<)$ in the infinitary logic $L_{\omega_1 \omega}$. Therefor we define strict order as usual:

- $\forall x,y,z ~~ (x<y \land y<z)\rightarrow x<z$
- $\forall x,y ~~ x<y \rightarrow \neg(y<x)$

We define that it has no end points:

- $\neg \exists x \forall y (x \neq y \rightarrow x<y)$
- $\neg \exists x \forall y (x \neq y \rightarrow x>y)$

Obviously, the successor relation $S$ is definable. Then we use infinitary logic for the first time to express that the order is not dense:

$\varphi^n(x,y):=S^n(x)=y$

$\Phi := \{\varphi^n(x,y) \mid n < \omega\}$

- $\forall x,y  (x<y \rightarrow ~\lor\Phi)$

Thus, we express that between two element $x<y$ there can only be a finite number of elements in between. Is that a correct and complete characterization of the classes isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z},<)$? Intuitively think it is but I do not know how to proof the correctness.

Comment: I always forget. Does $L_{\omega_1\omega}$ means countably quantifiers and finitely connectives, or the other way around?

Comment: Finitely many quantifiers and countable conjunctions and disjunctions.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: would it help at all to have countable quantifiers without infinite connectives?

Comment: @tomasz: No, I clearly didn't think it through when I posted the comment. I did think about what your comment points later on, though... I decided not to delete my comment though because it may help future visitors and should save them this contemplation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the order is nowhere dense is expressible in $L_{\omega\omega}$. We simply say that every point has a successor.

What you expressed is that the order is the countable union of finite intervals. Namely for every $x$ and $y$, if $x<y$ then by applying the successor some finitely many times from $x$ we arrive $y$.

Equally, but perhaps more insightfully, we could have said: $$\exists x\forall y\left(\bigvee\Phi(x,y)\lor\bigvee\Phi(y,x)\right)$$

Namely there is some point that every thing is generated by a finite application of the successor and co-successor.

Now suppose that $(M,\prec)$ is a structure which satisfies that $\prec$ is a linear order which is nowhere dense, and satisfies the property written above, fix some $x_\mathbb Z$ and $x_M$ which satisfy the role of $x$ in the sentence, and you have but a unique way to extend the function to an isomorphism now.

Comment: I think you are right so it would be expressable in $L_{\omega\omega}$. But this is kind of confusing regarding [Exercise 1.4.(i)](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CE4QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhomepages.math.uic.edu%2F~marker%2Finf.pdf&ei=_7ryUNzBJNGVswbk-4G4DQ&usg=AFQjCNES5NVQZ27xILVBAivPS24dr7n10w&sig2=ACCE8ovchE3f4pcIyr-oUg&bvm=bv.1357700187,d.Yms&cad=rja). This exercise could have easily been restricted to first order logic if you are right.

Comment: @joachim: But in $L_{\omega\omega}$ you cannot express the fact that every interval is finite. For example $\Bbb Z\times2$ would be a model of the nowhere dense linear ordering where every point is a successor, and has a successor. But you would have an infinite interval.

Comment: Can you give an example of an infinite interval in $\mathbb{Z} \times 2$?

Comment: @joachim: $\{x\mid (0,0)<x<(0,1)\}$, this interval contains all the pairs of the form $(k,0)$ for positive $k$ and $(m,1)$ for negative $m$.

Comment: Thanks! That helps me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing that $<$ is linear, and not merely a partial order.  Otherwise, any structure where $<$ is interpreted as the empty relation will satisfy your axioms.  So add
$$\forall x, y (x = y\ \vee\ x < y\ \vee\ y < x)$$
Given an arbitrary $(M, \prec)$ structure satisfying these axioms, you can construct an isomorphism between it and $(\mathbb{Z}, <)$.  Start by picking some $x \in M$, then define $f : \mathbb{Z} \to M$ by $f(n) = S^n(x)$.  As an exercise you can show that this is an isomorphism.  NB: for this to make sense, you'll need to prove (easily) that $S$ is a total, injective function.